# pandas convert NA values to the value before it

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to convert a pandas series of `1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, etc`
to `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, etc`.

What should do in order to replace the NA values with the integer before it.

Comment: series.fillna(method='ffill') try this!

Comment: When someone answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try [series.fillna(method='ffill')](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html)